# T-SNE Scatter Plot with Legend Based on the Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

The T-SNE scatter plot I have prints fine, but prints out all the same color and there isn't a legend. I'm having huge trouble with this. For SeaBorn it would be the 'hue', for Matplotlib it would be defining 'c'. All in all, I really need help defining a legend that has A ,B, C (the column names) and linking it(A,B,C) to a color on the scatter plot.

My data is as follows:

```
  A    B    C
 1.0  2.0  3.0
 4.0  5.0  6.0
 7.0  8.0  9.0

a = pd.DataFrame(data_files, columns = ['A'])
b = pd.DataFrame(data_files, columns = ['B'])
c = pd.DataFrame(data_files, columns = ['C'])

test_array = [a,b,c]
data_elem  = pd.concat(test_array, axis = 1, sort = False)

model     = TSNE(n_components = 2, perplexity = 50, learning_rate = 100, random_state  = None)
tsne_data = model.fit_transform(data_elem)
tsne_df   = pd.DataFrame(tsne_data)

htw = tsne_df.to_numpy(copy = True)
tsne_df['tsne_x'] = htw[:, 0]
tsne_df['tsne_y'] = htw[:, 1]

sns.scatterplot(
      x       = "tsne_x",
      y       = "tsne_y",
      #hue     = "",       <--issue is here
      palette = "Greens",
      data    = tsne_df,
      legend  = "full",
      alpha   = 0.3

   )

plt.xlabel("Dimension_X")
plt.ylabel("Dimension_Y")

plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

Nothing I've tried works. I keep getting errors i.e. KeyError or others by trying to define the 'hue' or 'c' if you're using matplotlib

Comment: What have you actually tried, and what was the full error of the most recent attempt or attempts?

Comment: @G.Anderson I tried:tsne_df['col']: ["A"]*len(a) + ["B"]*len(b) + ["C"]*len(c)

hue ="col"
` 
error was: ValueError: Could not interpret input 'col'

Comment: I also tried dropping the labels and adding them to a separate variable, but I don't think I did it correctly

Comment: If you want to use seaborn you need to melt your dataframe from wide form to long form. If you want to use matplotlib, you can loop over the columns `for col in df.columns: plt.scatter(df.index.values, df[col].values, label=col)`. If you want to use pandas you could just do `df.plot.scatter()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest do I melt the dataframe before or after putting it through the tsne?

Comment: Plotting is unrelated to machine learning.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm using the T-SNE for machine learning

Comment: What I mean is that you need to first get you the results of your machine learning before you start thinking about plotting it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest well what I was trying to do is, plot the (x,y) points that come out of the T-SNE (which it does) but I don't know which points go with which column (the labeling). From there, I was going to do some machine learning based off the cluster of the known points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I solved it. 
Make sure that before putting the DataFrame in the T-SNE that you separate the data from the labels.

```
data_elem_data                  = data_elem
data_elem_label                 = labels go here (must be 1 dimensional)
```

For me, I needed to flatten data_elem_label, before combining it with everything.

```
data_elem_label  = data_elem_label.values.flatten()
```

T-SNE creates two columns (x,y) so add a third column, which will be a label column. So... add the separated label column (from the beginning) to the completed T-SNE.

I.e.:

```
tsne_df = pd.concat([tsne_df, pd.Series(data_elem_label)], axis = 1)
```

And that's what worked for me.